# How to implement dispatcher timer in class and call it

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

So I'm working on an application that will need a timer on every page counting by the second. I figured it would be best to have the actual function on a class and have it called by the pages that need it. What I do know is how to get the timer working in a page... What baffles me is how to get it working in a class.

Needless to say, I'm failing.

Here's what I've done in the class:

```
    namespace Masca
    {
    public class timer
    {

    public void StartTimer()
    {
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

And what I've done in a page I need the timer in

```
namespace Masca
{

public partial class signup : Elysium.Controls.Window
{
    public timer timer;

    public signup(string Str_Value)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        tag.Text = Str_Value;
    }

    public void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now;
        this.doc.Text = datetime.ToString();
    }
```

I can't get the 'dispatcherTimer_Tick' event to know it's supposed to get it's instructions on how to work from the class 'timer'.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to add an event to your timer class:

```
public class timer
{

public event EventHandler TimerTick;

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TimerTick != null)
        TimerTick(this, null);
}
```

So that in your Window you can just listen to this event.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to expose either your own event or delegate from your `timer` class. The external classes subscribe to this event/delegate and you raise/call it from the `dispatcherTimer_Tick` method in your `timer` class.

I would do something like this in your `timer` class:

```
public delegate void TimeUp(); // define delegate

public TimeUp OnTimeUp { get; set; } // expose delegate
```

...

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now;
    if (OnTimeUp != null) OnTimeUp(); // call delegate
}
```

And from outside the class:

```
public timer timer;
```

...

```
timer.OnTimeUp += timerOnTimeUp;

private void timerOnTimeUp()
{
    // time is up
}
```